# How I can calculate the rows that exist in a other DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagrid, datatable, rows, datarow

I want to calculate values from a datatable and show this in a other datatable.

For Example:

datatable1: Source Table (Inputdatagrid)

position | value

```
001      | 2
002      | 1
003      | 5
001      | 1
```

datatable2: Destination Table (Resultdatagrid)

```
001      | 3    // 2 + 1
002      | 1
003      | 5
```

So I want make a foreach to look in every row in the first Datatable and then I look in the second table for the position value...if the position value doesn't exist then I create a new row...if the position value exist I calcualte the value wit  + .

how I can do this? can i do this with linq?

here my code:

```
...

int datagrid_input_counter = InputDataGrid.Rows.Count -1; //Anzahl Zeilen wird bestimmt

if (datagrid_input_counter > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagrid_input_counter; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow input_row = InputDataGrid.Rows[i]; // DataTable wird erstellt

        string datagrid_input_position = Convert.ToString(input_row.Cells[0].Value); //Stelle Position
        string datagrid_input_description = Convert.ToString(input_row.Cells[1].Value); //Stelle Beschreibung
        string datagrid_input_sellvalue = Convert.ToString(input_row.Cells[2].Value); //Stelle ert Verkauf

        //Add to Datatable
    }

    foreach (DataRow item in InputDataTable.Rows)
    {
        //How I get the result to ResultDatatable ????
    }
}
else 
{
    //Tabelle ist leer
}
```

Comment: `Inputdatagrid` contains two rows with `001`. Do you want to group by this columns and sum all values? It's confusing because you mention a second table(_"I look in the second table for the position value"_) which you don't show(apart from the result-table).

Comment: yes i want to group this 001 and make the sum :)

Comment: Why do you mention a second table then?

Comment: this i need later for a datagrid

Comment: have you tried Tables[0].Select method?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there actually is no second table but you want to group by the first column and sum all `value`s instead, you can use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
DataTable ResultDatatable = InputDataGrid.Clone(); // creates an empty table with the same columns
var col1Groups = InputDataGrid.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>(0));
foreach (var group in col1Groups)
{
    DataRow newRow = ResultDatatable.Rows.Add();
    newRow.SetField(0, group.Key);
    newRow.SetField(1, group.Sum(r => r.Field<int>(1))); // if it's not an int use int.Parse
}
```